# Azure Devops ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. The requested identity has not been assigned to this resource

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-managed-identity

I'm trying to debug a failing unit test in Azure Devops pipeline. The unit test uses Managed Identity to create a token which is then used to connect to SQL database. Here's the relevant code:

```
string[] scope = new string[] { "https://database.windows.net/" };
var credential = new ManagedIdentityCredential(managedIdentityId);
var accessToken = await credential.GetTokenAsync(new TokenRequestContext(scope)); // This line throws
// ...
// then later in the code we use the token like this
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
connection.AccessToken = accessToken.Token;
connection.Open();
```

The exception from the line "await credential.GetTokenAsync(...)" is:

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Azure.Identity.CredentialUnavailableException: ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. The requested identity has not been assigned to this resource.
Status: 400 (Bad Request)
Content:
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Identity not found"}
Headers:
Content-Length: 68
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
```

My question is when it says "Identity not found", what identity is it referring to? Is it the Managed Identity I'm using the code? Or is it some identity that the Devops pipeline's using? A number of documents indicates that you should create the user "CREATE USER <Azure_AD_principal_name> FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER". We've already done that and I can find the entry for the managed identity in the sys.database_principals table shown below. I've verified that the OBJECTID match the Managed identity we're using.

```
name    principal_id    type    type_desc   SID OBJECTID
MYSMI-Integration   6   E   EXTERNAL_USER   0xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Also, I understand that Managed Identity is not available locally. In this case, it's from the unit test that runs in Devops pipeline. Is Managed Identity restricted from being used in Devops pipeline?

Comment: you would need to grant the service principal running your pipeline permission to the database so ManagedIdentityCredential won't work here.